# Instantiating a ViewController when there's no storyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a rather simple iOS app build using `MvvmCross`.I need to integrate a few screens from a different project. In said project I'm using a story board and instantiates my view like below

```
Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("Controller")
```

However when integrated into this particular project it throws because StoryBoard of the ViewController is null. So how would one instantiate a controller and have all the subviews laid out in a case like this?

Answer (score 0):

If your current controller is not created from a storyboard, its `Storyboard` property is null. You can however load the storyboard itself using the static:

`UIStoryboard.FromName(string name)`

This will get you a storyboard reference and from there you can use

`InstantiateviewController(string storyboardId)`

Comment: what should be provided as the second argument `bundle`? I've tried all in NSBundle._AllBundles to no avail

Comment: @RuneFS Simple answer: `null`

Comment: I tried that, I tried the getting the bundle from the bundle identifier. Same problem the story board isn't found. I've circumvented the issue by doing the instantiation manually and manually laying out the subviews

Comment: I presume your storyboard is not using the correct build setting. Create a new project and see what its "build action" is and use the same one.